# How to have a teardown function in module scope based on running test result

Tags: python, python-3.x, testing, pytest, fixtures

I want to clean up some files after all tests pass. If they fail, keep them for debug. I read https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/example/simple.html#making-test-result-information-available-in-fixtures so I have the following in my `conftest.py`:

```python
@pytest.hookimpl(tryfirst=True, hookwrapper=True)
def pytest_runtest_makereport(item, call):
    # execute all other hooks to obtain the report object
    outcome = yield
    rep = outcome.get_result()

    # set a report attribute for each phase of a call, which can
    # be "setup", "call", "teardown"

    setattr(item, "rep_" + rep.when, rep)


@pytest.fixture(scope="module", autouse=True)
def teardown(request):
    yield
    # request.node is an "item" because we use the default
    # "function" scope
    if request.node.rep_setup.failed:
        print("setting up a test failed!", request.node.nodeid)
    elif request.node.rep_setup.passed:
        #clean up my files
```

however, I got the error:

```
AttributeError: 'Module' object has no attribute 'rep_setup'
```

The only difference from doc example is that my teardown has '`scope=module'`. But I have to do this because I want to clean up files after all tests pass, some files are used by all tests. If I use the default scope which is 'function' level, it will clean up after each test case rather than after the whole module. How can I fix this?

Update: Before I had 'hook', I still had the `teardown` which is "module" level, and it worked fine, meaning it cleaned up all files for me after all tests running, the only problem is that it will clean up for me no matter tests pass or fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are in module scope, `request.node` represents the module, not a single test. If you want just check for failed tests, you can check the session:

```py
@pytest.fixture(scope="module", autouse=True)
def teardown(request):
    yield
    if request.session.testsfailed > 0:
        print(f"{} test(s) failed!", request.session.testsfailed)
    else:
        #  clean up my files
```

I'm not sure if there is any information about setup failures in the request at this point, if you are only interested in these.
In this case you could implement a file scoped fixture which sets a flag in case of a setup failure, and use that, something like:

```py
SETUP_FAILED = False

@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
def teardown_test(request):
    yield
    if request.node.rep_setup.failed:
        global SETUP_FAILED
        SETUP_FAILED = True

@pytest.fixture(scope="module", autouse=True)
def teardown_module():
    global SETUP_FAILED
    SETUP_FAILED = False
    yield
    if SETUP_FAILED:
        print("At least one test setup failed!")
    else:
        #  clean up my files
```

This is not nice, and maybe someone knows a better solution, but it will work.
You could also collect information about the tests where the setup failed if needed.